# Number TypeError with Mongoose Model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

There's a 500 internal server error, for `Error: TypeError: path must be a string`

The browser console points to ItemCtrl.js:35

```
console.log('Error: ' + data);
```

The stack trace for the error looks like this:

> TypeError: path must be a string
>       at Query.where (/Users/Name/Downloads/dev/v16/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:593:11)
>       at Function.where (/Users/Name/Downloads/dev/v16/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1040:18)
>       at model. (/Users/Name/Downloads/dev/v16/app/models/item.js:44:35) ...

It seems the error derives from a line in */app/models/item.js*
specifically in the `else if` statement..
because with the `else if` commented out, both the `if` works and the `else` works..

```
// load mongoose since we need it to define a schema and model
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    position: Number
});

// before validation starts, the number of Items is counted..afterwards, the position is set
ItemSchema.pre("validate", function(next) {

    var doc = this;

    // if 'position' is not filled in, fill it in
    // not using !position because 0 might be a valid value
    if(typeof doc.position !== "number") {
        // count the number of Items *
        // use mongoose.model to fetch the model because it is not compiled yet
        mongoose.model("Item").count(function(err, num) {
            // if there was an error, pass it to next()
            if(err)
                return next(err);

            // set the position, then call next();
            doc.position = num;
            return next();
        });
    } else if(typeof doc.position == "number") {

        console.log('yes, a number');

        // check if there is an existing document with the same position
        // use mongoose.model to fetch the model because the model is not compiled yet
        mongoose.model("Item").where({_id: {$ne: doc._id}, position: doc.position}).count( function (err, count) {

            // if there was an error, pass it to next()
            if(err)
                return next(err);

            // if there is a doc with the SAME position, execute an update to MOVE DOWN all the $gte docs
            if(count > 0) {
                // use mongoose.model to fetch the model because the model is not compiled yet
                mongoose.model("Item").update({position: {$gte: doc.position}}, {position: {$inc: 1}}, {multi: 1}, function(err, numAffected) {

                    console.log(numAffected);

                    // Call next() (with or without an error)
                    next(err);
                });

            } else {
                //  there are no docs that need to move down, so call next()
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        //  there is no need to count or update positions, so call next()
        next();
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

> - The path of the data is this:
> - form field in /public/views/CreateItem.html
> - to /public/js/controllers/ItemCtrl.js
> - to /public/js/services/ItemService.js
> - to /app/routes.js
> - to /app/models/item.js
> - and the data can be viewed in json at localhost:8080/api/items

/public/views/CreateItem.html

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- BIND THESE VALUES TO formData.value IN ANGULAR -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="Item" ng-model="formData.title">
        <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="0" ng-model="formData.position">
    </div>
    <!-- createItem() WILL CREATE THE NEW ITEM VIA ANGULAR THROUGH NODE API TO MONGOOSE -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createItem()">Add Item</button>
</form>
```

/public/js/controllers/ItemCtrl.js

```
angular.module('ItemCtrl', [])

// inject the Item service.factory into our controller
.controller('ItemController', function($scope, $http, Items, isEmptyObjectFilter) {

        $scope.formData = {};

        // CREATE ==================================================================
        // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
        $scope.createItem = function() {

                // validate the formData (using our exentions.js .filter) to make sure that something is there..if form is empty, nothing will happen
                if (!isEmptyObjectFilter($scope.formData)) {

                        // call the create function from our service (returns a promise object)
                        Items.create($scope.formData)

                                // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new items
                                .success(function(data) {
                                        $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                                        $scope.items = data; // assign our new list of items
                                })
                                .error(function(data) {
                                        console.log('Error: ' + data);
                                });
                }
        };
});
```

/public/js/services/ItemService.js

```
angular.module('ItemService', [])

// super simple service
// each function returns a promise object 
.factory('Items', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/items');
        },
        create : function(itemData) {
            return $http.post('/api/items', itemData);
        }
    }
});
```

/app/routes.js

```
// load the item model
var Item = require('./models/item');

// expose the routes to our app with module.exports
module.exports = function(app) {

    // create item and send back all items after creation
    app.post('/api/items', function(req, res) {

        console.log(req.body.position);

        // create an item, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
        Item.create({
            title : req.body.title,
            position : req.body.position
        }, function(err, item) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            // get and return all the items after you create another
            Item.find(function(err, items) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(items);
            });
        });

    });
};
```

Comment: Try `{$inc: {position: 1}}`, not `{position: {$inc: 1}}`, assuming that line 44 is the `.update()` statement that triggers the error.

Comment: @RikkusRukkus thanks, will try that out.. line 44 is the         `mongoose.model("Emotion").where({_id: {$ne: doc._id}, position: doc.position}).count( function (err, count) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the mongoose API doesn't actually use `where` the way you are attempting to.

The docs for v3.8.8 of mongoose for [Model.where](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.where) show that you can use it in an ActiveRecord style way, chaining property names (like `'age'`) with criteria methods (like `gte`) to form a query:

```
User.find({age: {$gte: 21}, callback)
```

is equivalent to

```
User.where('age').gte(21).exec(callback)
```

Your code uses the hash-of-conditions style of `Model#find` instead of the chained methods style of `where`.

This is the line that should be rewritten:

`mongoose.model("Item").where({_id: {$ne: doc._id}, position: doc.position}).count( function (err, count) {`

The easiest thing to do would be to remove the `.count` at the end and just change the `.where` to a `.count`, since mongoose's `Model#count` takes a hash of conditions as you have here. The code should work like this:

`mongoose.model("Item").count({_id: {$ne: doc._id}, position: doc.position}, function (err, count) {`

If you want to use the `.where` syntax you'd need to do it like this:

`mongoose.model("Item").where('_id').ne(doc._id).where('position').equals(doc.position).count( function(err, count)`